# Getting undefined when trying to get a useParams() function with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to get the useParams value, however I am getting an undefined value... I don't know why since I am using the params id in `path='/investment/:id'`

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import AdminLayout from 'layouts/Admin/Admin.js';

import 'assets/scss/black-dashboard-react.scss';
import 'assets/demo/demo.css';
import 'assets/css/nucleo-icons.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';

import ThemeContextWrapper from './components/ThemeWrapper/ThemeWrapper';
import BackgroundColorWrapper from './components/BackgroundColorWrapper/BackgroundColorWrapper';
import InvestmentDetails from 'views/InvestmentDetails';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeContextWrapper>
    <BackgroundColorWrapper>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/investment/:id' exact component={InvestmentDetails} />
          <Route path='/admin' render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Redirect from='/' to='/admin/dashboard' />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </BackgroundColorWrapper>
  </ThemeContextWrapper>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// InvestmentDetails.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchInvestments } from 'services/Investments';
import { Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const InvestmentDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getInvestmentDetails = async () => {
      const investment = await fetchInvestments(id);
      console.log(id);
    };
    getInvestmentDetails();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div className='content'>
        <Row>
          <Col md='12'>
            <h1>{id}</h1>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default InvestmentDetails;



// the fetchInvestments function
export async function fetchInvestments(id = '') {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products/${id}`);
  return await response.json();
}
```

Hopefully some of you guys can help me out

Comment: I don't see an overt issue with your code. Have you tried killing your local dev server and restarting? If the issue persists do you think you could create a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces the issue and share the link in an update in your question?

Comment: Your code seems not to have problems. Could you share your code via sandbox?

Comment: Ok... here it goes my codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-meadow-be83j

Comment: Please, @DrewReese, notice that the investments are in the "investimentos" tab of the main menu

Comment: I see the `id` param being passed through to your "/investment/:id" path and component in your linked sandbox. Ah, so it's the linking from elsewhere in your app that there's an issue? Ok, checking again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching your code I don't see anything navigating to a "/investment/:id" path, but found that the `investimentos` tab renders the `InvestmentList` component and it links to an `"/admin/investment/:id"` path. I also found the `Admin` component appears to prepend a `"/admin"` prefix to any routes defined in `routes.js` that specify a layout value of `"/admin"`.

When I hit the "/investment/:id" path manually (*i.e. `"/investment/1234"`*) I was able to see the route `id` param (*i.e. `1234`*) in the `InvestmentDetails` component.

I think your router just needs to update the path it is trying to match for the investment details.

routes.js

```
{
  path: '/investment/',
  name: 'Novo Investimento',
  // rtlName: 'لوحة القيادة',
  icon: 'tim-icons icon-wallet-43',
  component: InvestmentDetails,
  layout: '/admin',
},
```

InvestmentList investment link:

```
<Link to={`/admin/investment/${inves.id}`}>
  {inves.name}
</Link>
```

index.js with router: Update the path prefix to include `"/admin"`

```
<Route path='/admin/investment/:id' exact component={InvestmentDetails} />
```

Comment: Yeah, @DrewReese, any tips on how can I overcome such behaviour?

Comment: @lucasbbs I'm sorry, overcome *what* behavior?

Comment: Of not displaying the id on the page

Comment: @lucasbbs Oh, sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough, I think you need to update the path  you are trying to match in the router to match that of what you are linking to within the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**.

Looking through your code I think the issue is to do with your API call. I think you are meant to be pointing to port 5000 not 3000 as I see you are mentioning it in your app.js

**Original**.

I don't really see anything wrong with this as I have written code like this before. The only thing I could think of changing is writing your use effect to include the id as a dependency so that it only runs when there is an id.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const getInvestmentDetails = async () => {
      const investment = await fetchInvestments(id);
      console.log(id);
    };
    getInvestmentDetails();
  }, [id]);
```

Comment: What port is your server running on? if it is 5000 then change your API call to const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`);

Comment: Actually I am using the port 4000, because the port 3000 is being used by json-sever...
HOw can I make both of them run on the same port?
The port 5000 is over there just by a mistake

Comment: You don't really want your server and client to be running on the same port if you are using a node js backend and react front end. Ideally have both of them running separately and then just point your front end to your backend.